# DockerToolbox-1.12.2 - Windows 7 - Error: connect ENOENT //./pipe/docker_engine

Tags: docker-toolbox

I have installed DockerToolbox-1.12.2.exe in Windows 7 from https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases/tag/v1.12.2 link. After installation, if I try to launch Kitamatic, I am getting 
[image]
Error: connect ENOENT //./pipe/docker_engine.

I have tried RETRY SETUP and USE VIRTUALBOX options available, but didn't helped much. Can anyone suggest, how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Because on Windows 7, docker is not supported native. So, you must have Virtual Box installed on your machine. If it is not already installed, you can re-run the docker toolbox installer, it asks you to install the Oracle VirtualBox with installation.

If it is already installed on your machine, open it and check if there is any default VM created in it and what is the error you are facing when you click on Use VirtualBox?